# Why is the Instragram API ignoring the min_id parameter for my request?

Tags: api, instagram

I'm making a request to [users/media/recent](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent) `GET` endpoint, but it's ignoring my `min_id` parameter. My final request looks like this (replace with your own `access_token` to test):

> `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=xxxxxxxx.xxx92d6.6584xxxxxe4d03a3cf2xxxcdb7da&min_id=1162106936627841123_10443137`

Results return, but the `min_id` is ignored and all posts are returned from the most recent one.

**How do I make the Instragram API take my `min_id` parameter into account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through first hand experience, unfortunately, Instagram API only returns the most recent media back to you no matter what the `min_id` is. A work around is to find and only use the `max_id` of the media instead. You may wish to save it to an array so that later you use can just pull out the `max_id`:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
           //min_id endpoint does not work for instagram API 
           //as it will always return the most recent photos. 
           //Using the max_id and going backward is the only workaround. 
           //Therefore accessing the max_id from the array that was saved earlier
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+ instagram_id +"/media/recent/?access_token=" + token + "&count=" + count +"&max_id=" + pageArray[currentPage-2], 
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function(obj) {
          //do something        
        },
        error: function() {
          //do something
        }
    });
```

Another way is to use the combination of `min_id` and `max_id` to get you a range of media. However, it looks like it excludes or doesn't show the media of the  `min_id` and `max_id`. That means only media between `min_id` and `max_id` are returned to you.

Comment: Although I wasn't using jQuery, and I didn't use the max_id (because I found that unreliable too), I did a similar thing (saved the highest ID and then skipped any that were not lower than that ID), this basically explains what the issue is and a way to get round it so I'll accept as the answer.

Comment: If social network API's were cars, Facebook would be a Ferrari. Twitter would be a little turtle, and Instagram a Ford Pinto.